# Windows 7 Media Player and Codecs

Tags: windows-7, codec, htpc

We use our Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit PC as a Media PC.

If it matters, it is the Asus EB1501. A little slow, but it works.

In an effort to get .MKV files to play, I installed Shark007's codec pack. The .MKV files play now.

I got my hands on a few good .AVI files yesterday, and we were going to watch those. Microsoft shows [>> HERE <<](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/File-types-supported-by-Windows-Media-Center) that .AVI files are supported, so my guess is something in Shark007's pack changed something that was working before.

I really hate having to constantly fight these codecs, especially on something that is supposed to be a HTPC where the mouse and keyboard are never touched and Media Center is running 100% of the time.

Does anyone know of a good solution?

Comment: You should list the specs of the AVI file. It will help narrow down the factors. Shark's Settign panel has an **analyze a file** button on the **Save Settings page.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only solution was to reformat and reinstall Windows.

The second time around, all I installed was the HAL media splitter. It is old, but only one component. It has been installed and running since about a week after posting this question, and has had no major problems. (All audio isn't great, but it works)

Comment: Update: I have been running the [Haali Media Splitter](http://haali.su/mkv/) only now for over two (2) years. There are very few files that it consistently will not play in Windows 7 Media Center (less than 1 in 1000), and these could be due to corrupt headers in the downloads. So, in my opinion, this HAL media splitter is all anyone really needs.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [K-Lite Codec Pack](http://www.free-codecs.com/k_lite_codec_pack_download.htm). It has it's own classy player and a lot of codecs. 
Plus it's free.

Comment: Seems like I used K-Lite a while back and had good results with it. Let me give it another go.

Comment: No, that did not work. Media Player Classic, which K-Lite installed, is able to play the AVI files so I know they are OK. Media Center and Media Player can not play these files.

Comment: @jp2code That's odd. I was able to play some formats without video but with sound. I will try for my self K-Lite Codec Pack.

Comment: @jp2code I need to play `*.MKV` file too :D

Comment: @jp2code Well I have downloaded and installed the K-Lite codec pack and it seems to work fine on my Windows XP

Comment: Yeah, I'm concerned some prior codec install left it's crap installed on the PC. Nothing but K-Lite is listed in the Programs folder, though.

Comment: @jp2code There is a configuration reset function in this product. Not sure is it in basic or full package, but It's saved me.

Comment: Even with proper codecs I have seen more than one file that worked better in the "Classic" Player that it came with.  I'd say if you find one it works ok in that's your "solution".

Comment: @OGChuckLow: The question is how to get this to work in Windows 7 Media Player - not Media Player Classic. "Classic" doesn't support the remotes, TV tuners, and a wealth of other things. It is good, but inferior, it seems. They just don't have the money that Microsoft has.

Comment: I recognize that and I feel made a succinct point that such is not the case nor is it going to BE the case.  Codec or not, some types of files will play better in other players.  I did not specify Classic except as in a general note.  You will also find other files will really only properly play in the player they include with various Codec Packs like the CCCP with the Zoom Player for MKV files.  You over inferred from what I said.